# How can I remount an external storage SD card?

Tags: external-sd

My external `sdcard1` has disappeared leaving only `sdcard0` emulated. I have looked in device/storage, and the folder is indeed gone. How can I mount or remount my external storage `sdcard1`?

Comment: fwiw I can mount my external exfat SD from a root terminal with `mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /storage/1726-1212` and then see the files in that target folder ... but only from the terminal. The file explorer app does not see it. A reboot should automatically remount the sdcard anyway though.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be via USB using an SD card adapter, I have one myself that I use for all my various devices, PC, Tablet and so on.  Especially handy when I am taking photo's to my PC.